# How can I flip keys with values in array and reset the keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I try to flip my arrays and keys and reset the keys. This is my array:

```
        "categories" => array:7 [▼
          "monkeys" => "200"
          "whales" => "100"
          "ants" => ""
          "elephants" => ""
          "fireflies" => ""
          "lemurs" => ""
          "penguins" => ""
        ]
```

The result I try to achieve is:

```
        "categories" => array:7 [▼
          0 => "monkeys"
          1 => "whales"
          2 => "ants"
          3 => "elephants"
          4 => "fireflies"
          5 => "lemurs"
          6 => "penguins"
        ]
```

My approach:

```
  $array = array_flip($value["categories"]);
  $array = array_values($array);
```

But unfortunately my empty values are removed:

```
"categories" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "monkeys"
      1 => "whales"
      2 => "penguins"
    ]
```

Comment: $array = array_keys($value["categories"]);

Comment: The empty values are not removed, but they are overwritten as you end up with multiple values with the same blank key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_keys` is what you might be looking for.

https://php.net/array_keys

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to "flip" anything, you just want:

```
$arr['categories'] = array_keys($arr['categories']);
```